# ASP.NET Core 5 JWT Authentication fails with response code 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement JWT based authentication in my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API. However, I always end up with the response code 401 when using my APIs marked with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Here's what I have so far. First, my `AccountController` issues a JWT if the user provides a valid username and password:

```cs
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/" + Constants.ApiVersion + "/Accounts")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly UserManager<AppUser>     _userManager;
  private readonly IPasswordHasher<AppUser> _passwordHasher;


  public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IPasswordHasher<AppUser> passwordHasher)
  {
    _userManager    = userManager;
    _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
  }


  [AllowAnonymous]
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("Token")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm]LoginBindingModel model)
  {
    if(model == null)
    {
      return BadRequest();
    }

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

    if(user == null || !await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
      return Unauthorized();
    }

    SymmetricSecurityKey    encryptionKey   = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TODO_Find_better_key_and_store_as_secret"));
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtTokenHandler = new();
    SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new()
    {
      Subject            = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("UserName", user.UserName) }),
      Expires            = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
      SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(encryptionKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    SecurityToken jwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    string        token    = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtToken);

    return Ok(token);
  }


  [HttpPost]
  [Route("ChangePassword")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody]ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
  {
    if(model == null)
    {
      return BadRequest();
    }

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    AppUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if(user == null)
    {
      return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
    }

    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);

    return GetHttpResponse(result);
  }


  ...
}
```

This code seems to work as it should. It returns a token that is successfully parsed by [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and contains the username I put into it.

Next, the Startup class looks as follows:

```cs
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    Configuration = configuration;
  }


  public IConfiguration Configuration
  {
    get;
  }


  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings)));
    services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(options =>
    {
      Configuration.GetSection(nameof(IdentityOptions)).Bind(options);
    });
    services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<AppUser>, Identity.PasswordHasher<AppUser>>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<AppUser>, UserStore>();
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
      options.SaveToken = true;
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
        ValidateIssuer           = true,
        ValidIssuer              = "whatever",
        ValidateAudience         = true,
        ValidAudience            = "whatever",
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey         = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TODO_Find_better_key_and_store_as_secret"))
      };
    });
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddControllers();
  }


  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
    if(env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
      endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
  }
}
```

I'm sending an HTTP POST request to the `Token` route which returns me the JWT. After that I'm sending an HTTP POST request with the necessary JSON data in the request body and `Authorization: Bearer <the JWT>` in the header to the `ChangePassword` route.

However, that always returns me response code 401 without any additional information or exception.

I'm unaware what the magic in `Startup.ConfigureServices` is actually supposed to do behind the scenes. Anyway, it obviously doesn't work. Does anyone know what is going on and what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, that always returns me response code 401 without any
> additional information or exception.

That is because you set `ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience` true but there is no `Issuer` and `Audience` in the generated token.

**One way** is that you can set `Issuer` and `Audience` in code:

```
SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
    Issuer= "whatever",
    Audience= "whatever",
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("UserName", user.Name) }),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(encryptionKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
```

**Another way** is that you can set `ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience` false:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,  //change here..
        ValidIssuer = "whatever",
        ValidateAudience = false,  //change here..
        ValidAudience = "whatever",
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TODO_Find_better_key_and_store_as_secret"))
    };
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, that is indeed the problem. The [JWT specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#page-9) states that both `Issuer` and `Audience` are optional and application specific. Hence, if you have no use for them in your application you might as well not use them at all.